# OL3 the text is incorrectly aligned

Tags: openlayers-2, style, openlayers, text, alignment

Using `OpenLayers3` I have observed an incorrect alignment of the text when styling the features of the `Cluster` source. Also the baseline of the text appears to be ignored.

The below code sample (or [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/dL3h58a9/)) presents how I am styling the features of the `Cluster` source. In short my goal is to present a single feature differently to a clustering of features.

```
    var aisLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        name: 'AIS Layer',
        source: clusterSource,
        style: function (feature, resolution) {
            var size = feature.get('features').length;
            var style;
            if (size === 1) {
                var theFeature = feature.get('features')[0];
                style = [
                new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 15,
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#000000'
                        }),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#ffffff'
                        })
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        textAlign: "Start",
                        textBaseline: "Middle",
                        font: 'Normal 12px Arial',
                        text: theFeature.get('name'),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#ffa500'
                        }),
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#000000',
                            width: 3
                        }),
                        offsetX: 0,
                        offsetY: 0,
                        rotation: 0
                    })
                })];
            } else {
                style = styleCache[size];
                if (!style) {
                    style = [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            radius: 12,
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#ffcc33'
                            }),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#000000'
                            })
                        }),
                        text: new ol.style.Text({
                            textAlign: "Center",
                            textBaseline: "Middle",
                            font: 'Normal 12px Arial',
                            text: size.toString(),
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#ffcc33'
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#000000',
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            offsetX: 0,
                            offsetY: 0,
                            rotation: 0
                        })
                    })];
                    styleCache[size] = style;
                }
            }
            return style;
        }
    });
```

**The problem:** The text is not centred for the clustered features (black circles), as if it still has the alignment setting used by the not clustered features (white circles). Also the baseline of the text appears to be ignored. To see the problem in action go to [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/dL3h58a9/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using capitalised letter within `textAlign` and `textBaseline`, the values must be in lowercase.

Next example, fixing that issue, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3h58a9/8/

Comment: Thank you Eric. That was exactly it. If only the doc was better this would have not taken place.
:)

Comment: You can get help from https://leanpub.com/thebookofopenlayers3. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

They fixed this in later versions (here's v3.7.0: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3h58a9/268/) so it's the same as the docs - but the values now have to be lowercase!

```
textAlign: "start",
textBaseline: "middle",
```